Wireguard connection gets stuck when CGNAT client changes IP
I have a Linux WireGuard endpoint with public, static IP configured as follows:
# cat /etc/wireguard/wg-wwan.conf 
[Interface]
Address = 10.20.30.248/31
ListenPort = 51833
PrivateKey = xxxxxxxxxx
Table = off

[Peer]
PublicKey = XqFhF5ZJT4FAsIIcUaX9asMzoFT5CvOQ6cahvRpvBHw=
AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0, ::/0

Then I have a RouterOS client ("peer") connecting to but is sits behind CGNAT. The connection works and stays up until the peer's internet connection stays up. However, when the internet connection re-connects (and the peer's public IP changes), the tunnel no longer works.
On Mikrotik side I get this error:
wg-bg1-wwan: [bgate1-wwan] xxxxxxxxxxxxxx=: Handshake for peer did not complete after 5 seconds, retrying (try 2)

However, Mikrotik router tries to re-connect. On Mikrotik side, I tried disabling/enabling all interfaces/peers, flushing connection tracking and even rebooting the router. I do see the packets from Mikrotik arriving on the Linux host via tcpdump.
I tried
conntrack --flush

but doesn't help.
The only thing that works is on Linux side
systemctl stop wg-quick@wg-wwan
systemctl start wg-quick@wg-wwan

It seems the Linux side gets confused by the change in IP of the client.
But what's going wrong here?

I experience this problem too, and it sounds similar to what others have experienced with CG-NAT, such as this discussion on the mailing list:
https://lists.zx2c4.com/pipermail/wireguard/2022-December/007893.html

I'm experiencing strange behaviour with wireguard: from time to time
connection 'freezes'.
Most often I'm observing this on an Android phone when connected from
my home over Starlink.
Server: latest Openwrt, Client: latest Android app.
The connection establishes and works fine for some time. After some
time the client still shows connection is established, but no incoming
data is coming.
On a server side 'latest handshake' goes into hours/days.
The freeze happens randomly, for no apparent reason and I think only
over starlink. I do not think I have ever observed this problem on
cell networks.
Reconnection solves the problem immediately.
I did some tcpdumping when the problem was present and found the following:

Server side sees incoming traffic from the client and sends responses.
On my own router connected to Starlink (i.e. interface between my
router and Starlink router) I see data going from the client to the
server - but no packets coming back.

So my 'hypothesis' is that somehow Starlink's CGNAT 'forgets' one side
of the connection - and so data continues to go in one direction, but
it doesn't come back. The thing with the wireguard is that it looks
like it doesn't change the outgoing port when it attempts to do
another handshake. This means that it continues using the same 'half
broken' connection forever.

It seems CG-NAT can get into a state where return traffic back through the NAT for a UDP path is no longer routed, even if there is continuing outgoing traffic.
In my testing I've seen that when the system gets into this state, blocking outgoing traffic for a few minutes actually allows it to recover - as if this is what's necessary for the CG-NAT to entirely forget about the route and allow it to be used anew.
A workaround is to prod the wireguard peer that's behind the NAT to switch to a new UDP port every so often. On some systems I run a systemd timer that once an hour does essentially:
# pick a new listen port
wg set wg0 listen-port 0 
# turn keepalives off and on again to trigger an immediate keepalive:
wg set wg0 <public-key-of-peer> persistent-keepalive 0 
wg set wg0 <public-key-of-peer> persistent-keepalive 25

Triggering an immediate keepalive updates the peer with our new listen port, which minimises downtime.
Obviously this can still lead to downtime if you only run it once an hour. It's a pretty lightweight thing to do so I don't see any reason not to run it every two minutes, I suppose.
Ideally I think we'd want Wireguard to implement that listen-port 0 means a new listen port is picked with every handshake, or after a failed locally-initiated handshake, or something like that. Otherwise UDP "connections" in CG-NAT seem to be able to get stuck in this limbo state where return traffic isn't routed, but outgoing traffic doesn't create a new entry in the NAT tables either, until everybody is silent for a bit.
